# concadenar un select en un ciclo while que llena una tabla php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, select, tabla-dinámica

Buenas tardes tengo este error aver si me pueden aydudar estoy llenado una tabla con datos de base de datos por medio de un ciclo while pero a su vez dos colunnas le estoy metiendo dos selec dependientes para interactuar entre ellos, que pasa el primer select me funciona perfectamente primero con el segundo de la primera fila  pero si cambio el primer select de la segunda fila me cambio todo los select de las segundas colunnas...... como podria encadenar o casar ese select o los select con su fila  espero su pronta ayuda .. les muestro el codigo los select los lleno con jquery

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(function(){

  // Lista de fase
  $.post( 'fase.php' ).done( function(respuesta  )
  {

   $( '.fase' ).html(respuesta );
  });

  // lista de r_fase
  $('.fase').change(function()
  {

   var la_fase = $(this).val();


    // Lista de r_fase

    $.post( 'r_fase.php', { fase: la_fase} ).done( function( respuesta  )
    {
      $( '.r_fase' ).html(respuesta);

     });
});
  
  // Lista de r_fase
  $( 'r_fase' ).change( function()
  {
   var fac = $(this).children('option:selected').html();
   alert( 'EL RESPONSABLE DE ESTA FACE ES :' + fac );
  });


})


</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
   // Lista de Continentes
   $.post( 'tecnicos.php' ).done( function(respuesta)
   {
    $( '.tecnicos' ).html( respuesta );
   });



</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

 <br>

 <table border="1" >
  <th class="bg-danger"><small>PLACA</small></th>
  <th class="bg-danger"><small>N° OT</small></th>
  <th class="bg-danger"><small>CLIENTE</small></th> 
  <th class="bg-danger"><small>CENTRO DE COSTO</small></th>
  <th class="bg-danger"><small>ASESOR</small></th>
  <th class="bg-danger"><small>MODELO</small></th>
  <th class="bg-danger"><small>COLOR</small></th>
  <th class="bg-danger"><small>MOTIVO DE INGRESO</small></th> 
  <th ><small>ESTADO DE FASE</small></th>
  <th ><small>RESPONSABLE DE FASE </small></th>                    
  <th><small>TECNICO</small></th>
  <th><small>PROXIMA REVISION</small></th>
  <th class="bg-danger"><small>FECHA DE ENTRADA</small></th> 
  <th ><small>DIAS EN TALLER</small></th>                                    
  <th><small>NOTA TORRE</small></th> 
  <th class="bg-danger"><small>MONTO</small></th>
  <th><small>NOTA</small></th>
  <th><small>CARRO LISTO</small></th>

  <?php 



  $sql="SELECT id,placa,n_ot,cliente,c_costo,asesor,modelo,color,m_ing,f_ini_taller 
  from torre ";
  $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

  $selec1 ;

  while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){


   ?> 
   <tr>
    <td class="hide"><?php echo $mostrar['id'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['placa'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['n_ot'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['cliente'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['c_costo'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['asesor'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['modelo'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['color'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['m_ing'] ?></td>




    <!--fase-->
    <td  ><select id="fase" class="fase"></select></td>
    <!-- RESPONSABLE D FACE-->
    <td  ><select name="r_fase" class="r_fase" ></select></td>


    <!-- TECNICOS-->
    <td><select name="tecnicos" class="tecnicos" >

    </select></td>

    <td></td>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['f_ini_taller'] ?></td>
    <td>  





    </td>
    <?php    
   }
   ?>



  </tr>
```

Comment: por favor no redactes en mayúsculas, pues es equivalente a gritar; por favor edita y corrige

Answer (score 0):

Al usar un selector de tipo clase jquery obtiene todos los combos que cumplen la condición de ese selector.

En esta función

```
// lista de r_fase

  $('.fase').change(function()
  {

    var la_fase = $(this).val();


    // Lista de r_fase

    $.post( 'r_fase.php', { fase: la_fase} ).done( function( respuesta  )
    {
        $( '.r_fase' ).html(respuesta);

     });
    });
```

Cambiar la siguiente la siguiente linea

```
    $( '.r_fase' ).html(respuesta);
```

por

```
    $(this).parents('tr').find( '.r_fase' ).html(respuesta);
```

Con parents() vas al elemento superior hasta encontrar 'tr' que seria la fila y con find() buscas en la fila la el elemento con la clase "r_fase"

https://api.jquery.com/parents/

https://api.jquery.com/find/